# How do I combine two tables with inner join and count some of the columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have two tables.

```
players: Username, Gang, Cash, Bank
gang: gangId, gangName
```

I want to select all gangids, and check how many players have the same gang id as the gang, and put it as total_members. And I also want it to combing the Cash and Bank for all members of the gang and put it as total_wealth. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried it first?

Comment: `select ... from ... join .... group by ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select g.gangid, 
       count(p.username) as total_members, 
       sum(cash+bank) as total_wealth
from gang g
left join players p on p.gang = g.gangid
group by g.gangid
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    SELECT p.gang, count(gang)
    FROM players p
    GROUP BY p.gang
```

It isn't clear if the column in players named "gang" is the ID or the Name.  This is assuming it's the ID.

Answer (score 0):

These should work close to what you want even though they may be slow:

`SELECT gang.gangId From gang left join Players ON gang.gangId = Players.gang`

`SELECT SUM(cash + bank) from Players.gang where gang = gangId`